# What is the machine encoding of 4 -- Is it 011 0100 (ascii) or 0100 (binary)?

Tags: encoding

I have a file "num.txt" which has only a number 4 in it.

With `xxd num.txt`, I found that the number is encoded as its ASCII code, `0x34` that is  `011 0100`. Why is the number not simply encoded as its binary form `0100`?

[Edit] My question is really about why 4 is encoded in ASCII, not in its binary form?

Comment: Decimal 52, in binary is `0011 0100`. This is the ASCII character four: "4".
Decimal 4    in binary is `0000 0100`. This is the ASCII character EOT. 
Three different representations for each of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is the *character* `'4'`, which is code point `0x34` in ASCII (and Unicode, for that matter).

In ASCII, code point `4` is `EOT` (end of transmission), commonly entered as <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd>. See, for example, the following table:

[image: ASCII table]

---

As to your edit:

> My question is really about why 4 is encoded in ASCII, not in its binary form?

The answer to that is that it's a text file. Whatever has created it has decided it wants to store the values as textual rather than binary information. It's really that simple :-)

If you want to go *deeper* into that particular question, you're going to have to ask the person who developed the software that creates the file, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you. I understand 4's ASCII code is 0x34. My question (edited) is really about why it is encoded into ASCII, rather than its binary form?

Comment: Because it's a text file not a binary file. The clue is in the file name: `num.txt`

Comment: @zell: updated the answer to cater for your edit.

Comment: @slebetman I do not think the file name says anything about its encoding. The name could have been num.bin for example.

Comment: @zell, there's probably a special circle of Hell (apologies in advance if that offends anyone, it was meant to be humour) reserved for people who put binary data into a file called `something.txt` :-)

Comment: @zell But in this case it states exactly what the file is - it is a text file. Like anything else when investigating/reverse engineering something it is just a clue, nothing more, but it is a clue nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

`011 0100` isn't 34. It's `0x34`. `0x34` is the ASCII encoding of the digit `'4'`.